# Xcode NSTimer get position object every millisecond

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nstimer

I need to get the position of the _propArrow (UIImageView) every .1sec at all time and use a NSLog to verify in the method (void)runScheduledTask

but does not operate every .1 sec.

only indicates the start and end of the movement of the animation

This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _propArrow.frame = CGRectMake(144, 291, 33, 71);


      aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.1 target:self selector:@selector(runScheduledTask) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];



}


- (void)runScheduledTask {

  NSLog(@"Position: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(_propArrow.frame));

}


- (IBAction)fire:(id)sender {



[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{

                              _propArrow.frame = CGRectMake(144, 0, 33, 71);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                     }];



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in most UIKit animated properties, the new value gets set *immediately* from the perspective of your code; it's the *displayed* value that actually animates. Reading animatable properties like `UIView.frame` should never give you an intermediate value (the main exception is UIScrollView which does its own thing for animated scrolling).

If you want "approximately what's being displayed on screen", you need to access the CoreAnimation "presentation layer":

```
#import <QuartzCore/CALayer.h>

- (void)runScheduledTask {
  NSLog(@"Position: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(_propArrow.layer.presentationLayer.frame));
}
```

Also consider using `CADisplayLink` if you want a callback that runs every frame.

Comment: Works!!
Thank you. This is what I was really looking =)

Answer (score 2):

First, according to the [NSTimer docs,](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) that class has an effective resolution of about 50-100 ms. So using it to do anything at 1 ms intervals is bound to fail.

Second, even if NSTimer could handle 1 ms intervals, you're not even asking it to do that:

> `aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.05...`

Your code schedules the timer to run ever 0.05 s, which is to say every 50 ms.

Third, the screen doesn't update at anything close to 1 ms intervals, so the actual position of your image on the screen will change much less often than that.

So, what exactly are you trying to accomplish here? If you want to know where the object *would be* in the real world with continuous motion, you can calculate that for any point in time.

Comment: And how I can get the position of the object every millisecond?
any suggestions?

Comment: sorry i have a error in my question And how I can get the position of the object every .1 seconds?

Comment: I need every .1sec the object position in Y
NSlog.....
2012-10-08 20:49:50.693  Y: {{144, 291}, {33, 71}}
2012-10-08 20:49:50.793  Y: {{144, 291}, {33, 71}}
2012-10-08 20:49:50.893  Y: {{144, 291}, {33, 71}}
2012-10-08 20:49:50.994  Y: {{144, 0}, {33, 71}}
2012-10-08 20:49:51.093  Y: {{144, 0}, {33, 71}}
2012-10-08 20:49:51.193  Y: {{144, 0}, {33, 71}}
2012-10-08 20:49:51.293  Y: {{144, 0}, {33, 71}}